# Dash DataTable field doesn't update unless I click enter

Tags: python, frontend, plotly-dash

I'm trying to implement an editable table in Dash following the example "Updating Columns of the Same Table": [https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/editable](https://stackoverflow.com)

The callback is only triggered when I click enter, I want to be able to update the data in a cell and it updates when I click anywhere else on the page. Currently when I do that, the data reverts to the original value.

Code:

```
layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='computed-table',
        columns=[
            {'name': 'Input Data', 'id': 'input-data'},
            {'name': 'Input Squared', 'id': 'output-data'}
        ],
        data=[{'input-data': i} for i in range(11)],
        editable=True,
    ),
])


@callback(
    Output('computed-table', 'data'),
    Input('computed-table', 'data_timestamp'),
    State('computed-table', 'data'))
def update_columns(timestamp, rows):
    for row in rows:
        try:
            row['output-data'] = float(row['input-data']) ** 2
        except:
            row['output-data'] = 'NA'
    return rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback is also triggered when clicking anywhere on the page, that is not the problem. Put a breakpoint or a print statement inside the callback and you can see that this is the case.

If you change a value in the "Input Data" column the corresponding value in the "Input Squared" becomes the input data value to the power of 2 (If valid number).

Now if you edit a value in the "Input Squared" column it's still going to set the value based on the "Input Data" column.

The current behavior feels very logical to me. If you want the "Input Squared" column to have the values of "Input Data" squared, you shouldn't allow editing of the "Input Squared" column directly. So I'd recommend setting `editable` to `False` on the "Input Squared" column. Then it's clear you can't edit the column directly.

Comment: Thanks @5eb for assisting. If I enter 9 in the field where 10 is in "Input Data" and click anywhere else, it reverts back to 10. Perhaps the callback is not important as I'm not concerned with the "Input Squared" column, I just want my update to the field to remain once I click somewhere else (i.e. the field stays as 9 and doesn't revert back to 10).

Comment: "I just want my update to the field to remain once I click somewhere else" That should be the default behavior of the data table (As long as your own callbacks don't override the behavior).

Comment: Hi 5eb, did you test this? The example tables on plotly.com and my own table only change when I click enter. It is the same for my colleague

Comment: Yes, but the examples (https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/editable) work as well no? Or am I misunderstanding you?